# Using class-based views save a form with 2 related models (via foreign key)

Tags: django, django-forms

1. WANT TO DO

using CreateView I launch an hmtm page containing a form. This page has had two embedded forms sent in like {{address}} and {{ship}}. The ship model has a foreign key linking it to the address table address_id.  I can do this easily using function-based views, but I want to do it via class-based.

I create my models, then I do something like this in the view that launches the html page:

```
context = {
    'address_form': AddressForm(),
    'ship_form': ShipForm(),
    )
}
return render(request, 'app/registration.html', context)
```

The html looks sommething like this:

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {{ address_form }}
    {{ ship_form }}
    
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

When I click on submit, the form does connect to the database BUT it tries to save the ship form but it fails because it doesn´t have the address_id and of course, the reason is that the address_form could not be saved first, and this is what is blocking my progress.

I know I can do ´some´ manipulation inside the CreateView that launched the html page, like in here

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
```

but there is no way I can reach the address form, it only lets me alter the ship form.

I had an idea, but I don´t think this is the correct or djangonian way of doing it:

I could use ajax to save the address form from within the html page, and then in the

``def form_valid(self, form):`

I would use a function like latest_id or get_latest.

Does anyone know how to make it possible that the address form is saved first so that the subsequent form (ship_form) can pick its latest id?

thanks

UPDATE:

The views

```
class AddView(CreateView):
    model = Ship
    fields = '__all_'
    template_name  = 'theform.html'

 context = {
    'address_form': AddressForm(),
    'ship_form': ShipForm(),
   
}
return render(request, 'app/theform.html', context)
```

I have scanned the whole of the internet for two days but there is no place where they fully address this. There are function-based approaches, there are class-based views but only for one table, but none like the issue here.

Comment: can you share your views?